# Why SQLCommandBuider not DELETING?

Tags: asp.net, sqldataadapter, sqlcommandbuilder

In the following code UPDATE is working but DELETE is not working. When I DELETE row it delete it and GridView1 does not show it but database still has it. `customers` has `PrimaryKey`.

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(conString))
        {
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
            adapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("select * from customers", connection);
            SqlCommandBuilder builder = new SqlCommandBuilder(adapter);
            connection.Open();
            DataTable customers = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(customers);
            // code to modify data in DataTable here
        customers.Rows.RemoveAt(rowIndex);
            GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
            GridView1.DataSource = customers;
            GridView1.DataBind();
            adapter.Update(customers);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to remove the row from the DataTable but [delete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.data.datarow.delete%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) it.

The DataRow's [DataRowState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowstate.aspx) must be modified to `deleted`, then the DataAdapter knows that it must delete it in the datasource.

Following will delete it:

```
customers.Rows(rowIndex).delete();//now DataRow's DataRowState is Deleted
adapter.Update(customers);        // now it's actually deleted
```

Futher informations: [MSDN How to: Delete Rows in a DataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/feh3ed13%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

By the way, following would prevent the DataRow to be deleted, if you've changed your mind:

```
customers.Rows(rowIndex).RejectChanges();
```

The RowState will change back to `Unchanged`.
This works either for the [DataRow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.rejectchanges.aspx) or for the [whole DataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.rejectchanges.aspx).